tp-link Archer tx1750U nano wireless USB adapter not detected
My tp-link Archer tx1750U nano wireless USB adapter is not being detected as a wireless adapter in ip link. I am using arch linux. This is the result of lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:5285 IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c7a:0576 LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec EH576
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 35bc:0108 Realtek 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


It should be supported by this driver: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8852au-dkms-git

@ChanganAuto it is still not being detected and my lsusb is giving the same output.
This is the result of lsmod | grep 8852au:
8852au              14503936  0

I realized the chipset was the rtl8852bu and created a fork with my PID and VID here. I can connect to networks but the LED functionality will not work.
